# Combining type bounds in Scala

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds

Let's say I have a function such as:

```
def foo[T<:U <:V](t:T): Unit
```

I want to know if there is a way of combining these two in a type `W` so that I can have:

```
def foo[T<: W](t: T): Unit
```

The use case for this is:

```
trait FooTrait{
   type W
   def foo[T<: W](t: T): Unit
}
```

I might have two different implementations of foo, one of them with a simple `W1` type bound whereas the other one is `T<:W1 <:W2` I want the more complex one to define a `W3` so that I can have:

```
def foo[T<: W3](t: T): Unit
```

Similiarly, I want to be able to do these with type classes. So if I have:

```
def bar[T<:U :V](t:T): Unit
```

I want to have

```
def bar[T:X](t:T): Unit
```

The use case for this is essentially the same as the earlier case.

is this possible?

Comment: Your question is absolutely not clear. Which ones of the single-char types are classes/traits and which ones are generic types? What is the benefit of such combination? Could you provide imaginary usage examples?

Comment: added the use case.

Answer (score 3):

In the first part of your question, the syntax isn't even valid.
If you want to impose multiple upper bounds `U`, `V` on some type `T`,
you have to use `with` keyword anyway:

```
trait A
trait B

def f[X <: A with B](x: X): Unit = ???
```

This here doesn't work:

```
// def f[X <: A <: B](x: X): Unit = ??? // doesn't compile
```

To address the second part of your question, I would like to 
explain why something like `with` doesn't work for typeclasses.

This here does work:

```
trait Foo[X]
trait Bar[X]

def g[X: Foo : Bar](x: X): Unit = ???
```

This here doesn't work:

```
// def g[X: Foo with Bar](x: X): Unit = ??? // nope
```

Why? Because

```
def foo[X: Y](x: X): Ret = ???
```

is actually a shortcut for

```
def foo[X](x: X)(implicit y: Y[X]): Ret = ???
```

If you would try to somehow amalgamate two different typeclasses `Foo` and `Bar`,
this would result in the following desugared code:

```
def foo[X](x: X)(implicit superPowerfulThing: (Foo somehowGluedWith Bar)[X]): Ret = ???
```

But this is obviously not something that you should want.
Instead, what you want is:

```
def foo[X](x: X)(implicit foo: Foo[X], bar: Bar[X])(x: X): Ret = ???
```

In this way, the two requirements `Foo` and `Bar` can be supplied independently,
which wouldn't work if you requested some `superPowerfulThing` that implements
both `Foo` and `Bar` at once.

Hope that clarifies why something works or doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the syntax error in the first case. So you have answered the first part. it's basically `type W = U with V` as for the second part, yeah I had actually arrived at your conclusion myself but failed to show that in the example. I believe I am looking for some way of specifying the type-class bounds with existential types. something like: `[T] forSome { type T where T satisfies this and that }`

Comment: I guess first step towards answering that question would be: is there a way of representing the type class shorthand notation with existential type representation. I guess not, because as you pointed out, we have two parameters of two types one T, one of the type `_<:U` while the other one is `_ <: V[T]`. so we can't.

Comment: good point about the distinction between traits and generic types btw. I was thinking purely in terms of traits.

Answer (score 3):

Andrey Tyukin has correctly point out that `with` is probably the answer for your first question and that the second question has no direct solution. However if you are OK with indirect solutions, you might work this around by introducing a new type class that will says that the target types belongs to the two original type classes. Here is a simple example for imaginary typeclasses `Foo` and `Bar` and for a base trait `Base` with a specific implementation `ChildFooBar`:

```
trait Foo[X] {
  def doFoo(x: X): String
}

trait Bar[X] {
  def doBar(x: X): String
}

trait Base {
  type W[_]

  def baz[T: W](t: T): String
}

class ChildFooBar extends Base {

  import ChildFooBar._

  type W[X] = FooAndBar[X]


  override def baz[T: FooAndBar](t: T): String = {
    val foo = implicitly[Foo[T]]
    val bar = implicitly[Bar[T]]
    foo.doFoo(t) + bar.doBar(t)
  }
}

object ChildFooBar {

  @implicitNotFound("The type should provide both implicit Foo and implicit Bar.")
  case class FooAndBar[X](foo: Foo[X], bar: Bar[X])

  object FooAndBar {
    implicit def fromFooAndBar[X](implicit foo: Foo[X], bar: Bar[X]): FooAndBar[X] = FooAndBar(foo, bar)
  }

  // private is important here to avoid diversion of implicits
  private implicit def toFoo[X](implicit fooAndBar: FooAndBar[X]): Foo[X] = fooAndBar.foo
  private implicit def toBar[X](implicit fooAndBar: FooAndBar[X]): Bar[X] = fooAndBar.bar

}
```

Now if `SomeClass` is a member of both `Foo` and `Bar` typeclasses, then

```
case class SomeClass(foo: Int, bar: Double)

object SomeClass {
  implicit val foo: Foo[SomeClass] = new Foo[SomeClass] {
    override def doFoo(x: SomeClass) = s"foo = ${x.foo}"
  }
  implicit val bar: Bar[SomeClass] = new Bar[SomeClass] {
    override def doBar(x: SomeClass) = s"bar = ${x.bar}"
  }
}
```

the simple code

```
println(new ChildFooBar().baz(SomeClass(1, 2.0)))
```

will compile and work as expected.